# Articles doesn't display as inline objects in my page

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

Help me to find the reason why my articles don't show in one line even though it is told to be displayed as inline-block elements (each article has an image, h3 text, and a paragraph). Here is my CSS code:

```
#article_1{
width: 1000px;
margin: auto;
}
  
article{
    max-width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
article img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
<header><h1>News page</h1></header>

<section id="article_1">
    <article>
        <h3>Kamal has chosen the sexiest man alive!!!</h3>
        <div id="article_img" style="background:url(./photos/sex - Copy.jpg)"></div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. texttook a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </article>
</section>
<br>

<section id="article_1">
    <article>
        <h3>Kamal has chosen the sexiest man alive!!!</h3>
        <div id="article_img" style="background:url(./photos/sex - Copy.jpg)"></div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. texttook a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </article>
</section>
<br>

<section id="article_1">
    <article>
        <h3>Kamal has chosen the sexiest man alive!!!</h3>
        <div id="article_img" style="background:url(./photos/sex - Copy.jpg)"></div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. texttook a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </article>
</section>
<br>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some of your HTML so that we may reproduce the issue and better help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, it sounds like the text is wrapping?

Try this

```css
article{
    max-width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Let me know how that works!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, it only made the text one lined.

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet of your issue for us please?